# Move file from local to HDFS

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-pig

My environment uses Spark, Pig and Hive.

I am having some trouble to write a code in Scala (or any other language compatible with my environment) that could copy a file from a local file system to HDFS.

Does anyone have any advices on how I should proceed?

Answer (score 8):

The other answers didn't work for me, so I am writing another one here.

Try the following Scala code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path

val hadoopConf = new Configuration()
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConf)

val srcPath = new Path(srcFilePath)
val destPath = new Path(destFilePath)

hdfs.copyFromLocalFile(srcPath, destPath)
```

You should also check if Spark has the `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` variable set in the `conf/spark-env.sh` file. This will make sure that Spark is going to find the Hadoop configuration settings.

The dependencies for the `build.sbt` file:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-io" % "1.3.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.6.0"
```

Answer (score 5):

You could write a Scala job using Hadoop [FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html) API.
And use [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) from apache commons to copy data from InputStream to OutputStream

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;



val hadoopconf = new Configuration();
val fs = FileSystem.get(hadoopconf);

//Create output stream to HDFS file
val outFileStream = fs.create(new Path("hedf://<namenode>:<port>/<filename>))

//Create input stream from local file
val inStream = fs.open(new Path("file://<input_file>"))

IOUtils.copy(inStream, outFileStream)

//Close both files
inStream.close()
outFileStream.close()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Dependencies:


`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.6.0"`


`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-io" % "1.3.2"`


`libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.6.0"`

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that works for S3 (modified from above)

```
def cpToS3(localPath: String, s3Path: String) = {
  val hdfs = FileSystem.get(
               new URI(s3Path), 
               spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)

  val srcPath = new Path(localPath)
  val destPath = new Path(s3Path)

  hdfs.copyFromLocalFile(srcPath, destPath)
}
```